# Angular Firestore Multiple where

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn multiple parameter. Why it is still returning all collection values. it is not filtering. Thank you.

```
this.afsEmployeesRef = this.apiService.firestore.collection<Employees>('employees', ref =>
        ref.where('companyid', '==', this.settingsService.userCompany[0].companyid)
           .where('active', '==', 1)
           .orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
           .orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
           .orderBy('middlename', 'asc')
      );
      
if (this.selected_department != 'All'){
        this.afsEmployeesRef.ref.where('departmentid', '==', this.selected_department);
      }

if (this.selected_location != 'All'){
        this.afsEmployeesRef.ref.where('locationid', '==', this.selected_location);
      }

if (this.selected_role != 'All'){
        this.afsEmployeesRef.ref.where('role', '==', this.selected_role);
      }

if (this.selected_shift != 'All'){
        this.afsEmployeesRef.ref.where('shiftid', '==', this.selected_shift);
      }
      
this.afsEmployeesRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
          this.employees = data.map(e => {
            return {
              id: e.payload.doc.id,
              ...e.payload.doc.data()
            };
          });
          resolve(this.employees);
      });
```

Comment: Are all filters not working? or those 'if' only, but some ex. `where('active', '==', 1)` are working?

Comment: it is returning all documents, filter is not working

Comment: so `where('active', '==', 1)` is not working as well?